# How to get order id in Woocomerce Email

Tags: email, woocommerce

I try to get the order id when adding extra content in woocommerce email, is anyone knows what goes wrong with this...?
Thanks

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_content', 20 );

function add_content() {
global $woocommerce;
echo $order_id 
echo $order->id;
 }
```

Comment: You absolutely don't need `global $woocommerce;` as in the accepted answer… This is outdated and not necessary…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the parameter `$order` and get `$order->get_id();`

something like this:

```
function add_content( $order ) {
echo $order->get_id();
 }
```

Comment: I must've been too slow. :) But you don't need to global declare `$woocommerce` and if you need the woocommerce instance you should use `WC()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the [source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/fa2d74ffce0338838eef3df87384ddafc75b17c4/templates/emails/email-order-details.php#L66), `$order` is the first variable passed to the `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'so_43612005_add_content', 20, 4 );

function so_43612005_add_content( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // WooCommerce 3.0
    if( method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ) {
       $order_id = $order->get_id(); 
    // WooCommerce 2.6.x
    } else {
       $order_id = $order->id; 
    }
    echo $order_id;
}
```

Comment: Good idea on the `method_exists()` that way you can be forward and backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wdm_add_shipping_method_to_order_email', 10, 2 );
function wdm_add_shipping_method_to_order_email( $order, $is_admin_email ) {
    echo '<p><h4>Order Id:</h4> ' . $order->get_order_number() . '</p>';
}
```